# How can i write this JavaScript ternary shorter?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ternary

Here my ternary :

```
mode === 'edition' ? (this.editionMode = true, this.creationMode = false) : (this.creationMode = true, this.editionMode = false)
```

I think it's redundant, can i write this ternary in a better way ? Thanks !

Comment: Use a real `if` statement, not a conditional operator. You'd not using the values on the RHS, you're just using side effects.

Answer (score 5):

```
this.editionMode = mode === 'edition';
this.creationMode = !this.editionMode;
```

Comment: The first can be re-written as `this.editionMode = mode === 'edition'`

Comment: If you really want to be cryptic: `this.creationMode = !(this.editionMode = mode === 'edition')`